# Replacing DB Trigger mechanism

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I'm using SQL Server (2005). 
Today I have some tables that everytime the data inside them changes I get DB trigger
(implemented via the sql server trigger mechanism) and handles it.
the problem is that the trigger mechanism has bad performance and handling with it is not exaclly afun thing to do. now to my question. is anybody knows any diffrent way to get notification from sql server whenever a data on a specific table changes.(deleted,added,updated) ?

Comment: Show us your trigger code please...

Comment: Yep. Please post the trigger code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server [Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175110.aspx) were introduced in SQL Server 2005 and do exactly this. I agree it would be good to see what your trigger is doing though to gauge suitability for your specific case.

Answer (score -1):

No, not with 2005. 2008R2 has a mechanism for that, but in 2005 there is no alternative mechanism to triggers.